# CSS transform property compatiblity

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a border like `/`. I'm using following code. It displays fine in the Firefox, but display in opposite direction in the Chrome/Safari (starts from top and ends at right. How can I fix it?

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lo3pjjrj/2/

Answer (score 2):

You are using different transform functions (`skew` and `rotate`) for prefixed and unprefixed code. Use the same function, with only prefix as a difference. Also, it's recommended to write the unprefixed line after the prefixed one, since modern browsers may have both stable (preferred) and experimental implementations, and CSS applies the code that comes last.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
.box {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* add all applicable vendor prefixes here */
}
```